# Git: validating data and/or recovering from sloppy file synchronization?

Tags: git, unison

I use git, and I synchronize my files, including git's metadata, among several machines using a file synchronization utility (unison). Recently I mistakenly changed different files on two different machines, without properly synchronizing in between. I'm pretty sure I have correctly reconciled the files themselves, but I'm not completely sure that I now have the correct git metadata for the reconciled set of files.

Is there anything I should do to check for consistency? Should I simply do a git commit for the newly reconciled set of files?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have Unison synchronizing *all* of git's metadata (by which I suppose you mean the stuff in your project's `.git` directory), it should be fine to do a git commit. This will update git's metadata using the current version of the conflicting file (the version you want) and then you can sync these changes with Unison.